# Error tolerance not working in C++, when plotted against ODE45 in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, differential-equations, ode45

I am comparing the ODE solver of C++ (BOOST ODEINT) against MATLAB's ODE45. Each set of code has the same equations and initial conditions. When error tolerance is added to the C++ code, the difference between the two values (C++ and MATLAB) is quite large. The values of the two should be roughly the same. It does not make sense that the error tolerance addition would cause a large difference in values.

[image]

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <boost/array.hpp>
    #include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_adaptive.hpp>


    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

    const double sigma = 10.0;
    const double R = 28.0;
    const double b = 8.0 / 3.0;
    const float mu = 3.986e5;

    typedef boost::array< double, 6 > state_type;

    ofstream opfile;

    void lorenz(const state_type& x, state_type& dxdt, double t)
   {

        float r_2 = (pow(x[0],2) + pow(x[1],2) + pow(x[2],2));
        float r = sqrt(r_2);

        dxdt[0] = x[3];
        dxdt[1] = x[4];
        dxdt[2] = x[5];
        dxdt[3] = (-mu / pow(r, 3)) * x[0];
        dxdt[4] = (-mu / pow(r, 3)) * x[1];
        dxdt[5] = (-mu / pow(r, 3)) * x[2];

    }

     void write_lorenz(const state_type& x, const double t)
    {

      opfile << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2]<< '\t' << x[3] << '\t' 
      << x[4] << '\t' << x[5] << '\n'<< endl;

     }

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {

       double T = 4.2706e4;
       typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> stepper_type;
       state_type x = {3.1117e3 , 0 , 4.565e3, 3.0, 4.5, 6.8}; // initial conditions
       const double dt = 0.1;
       cout.precision(16);  // full precision output
    
       opfile.open("test_rk_dopri.txt");



      integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>(1E-9, 1E-9), lorenz, x, 0.0, T, dt, write_lorenz);

//integrate_const(make_dense_output(1.0e-6, 1.0e-6, runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type >()), lorenz, x, 0.0, T, dt, write_lorenz);

     opfile.close();

return 0;
 }
```

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
      %% ODE45 plotted against C++ odeint solvers
      %% initial conditions
      r0_vec = [3.1117e3;0;4.565e3];
      v0_vec = [3.0; 4.5; 6.8];
      mew = 3.986e5;


     %% Runge Kutta cash karp
     fid = fopen('test_cashkarp_Rk.txt', 'rt');
     a = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
     fclose(fid);
     rk_cashkarp = cell2mat(a);
     % t = linspace(0.1,10,length(rk_cashkarp));

     fid_1 = fopen('test_rk4.txt', 'rt');
     b = textscan(fid_1, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
     fclose(fid_1);
     rk_4 = cell2mat(b);
     % t = linspace(0.1,10,length(rk_4));

     fid_2 = fopen('test_rk_dopri.txt', 'rt');
      c = textscan(fid_2, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
      fclose(fid_2);
     rk_dopri = cell2mat(c);
     % t = linspace(0.1,10,length(rk_dopri));

     fid_3 = fopen('test_rk_fehlberg.txt', 'rt');
     d = textscan(fid_3, '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f');
     fclose(fid_3);
     rk_fehlberg = cell2mat(d);
     % t = linspace(0.1,10,length(rk_fehlberg));
     T =  4.2706e4;


    %%ODE45 function
     options = odeset('relTol',1e-6,'absTol',1e-6);
     tspan = rk_dopri(:,1);
       [t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) ODE_eqnsofMot(t,y,mew),tspan, [r0_vec; v0_vec],options);
       close all

      figure ('name','Postion Ode45')
      plot(rk_dopri(:,2)-y(:,1))
      % plot3(y(:,1),y(:,2),y(:,3),'.')


      % 
      % figure ('name','Postion rk4')
      % plot3(rk_4(:,2),rk_4(:,3),rk_4(:,4),'.')
          % 
      % figure ('name','Postion rkcashkarp')
      % plot3(rk_cashkarp(:,2),rk_cashkarp(:,3),rk_cashkarp(:,4),'.')
      % 
      % figure ('name','Postion rkdopri')
      % plot3(rk_dopri(:,2),rk_dopri(:,3),rk_dopri(:,4),'.')
      % 
      % figure ('name','Postion  rkfehlberg')
      % plot3(rk_fehlberg(:,2),rk_fehlberg(:,3),rk_fehlberg(:,4),'.')
      % 


      %%ODE45 function

      function dydt = ODE_eqnsofMot(t, y, mew)

      dydt = zeros(6,1); 
      r = sqrt(y(1)^2+(y(2))^2+(y(3))^2);

      dydt(1) = y(4);
      dydt(2) = y(5);
      dydt(3) = y(6);
      dydt(4) = (-mew/(r)^3)*y(1);
      dydt(5) = (-mew/(r)^3)*y(2);
      dydt(6) = (-mew/(r)^3)*y(3);


  end
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What equation are you solving? What does the graph represent? What does "quite large" mean? Quite large with respect to what?

Comment: @Evg this is to solve the two body problem in orbital mechanics. The graph represents the error between the C++ ODE solver and Matlabs ODE45. The error should be much smaller like 10^-9. Matlab is as close to accurate as possible, so there must be an error in the c++ code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a difference between the different implementations (I think they all follow the standard that Hairer and Shampine established). I get the same graph in python with the following short lines

```python
def grav(t,u): p,v = u[:3],u[3:]; a = -mu*p*sum(p**2)**-1.5; return *v, *a

mu, p0, v0 = 3.986e5, [3.1117e3 , 0 , 4.565e3], [3.0, 4.5, 6.8]
u0 = [*p0, *v0]
t = np.arange(0,4.2706e4, 0.1)

u6 = solve_ivp(grav, t[[0,-1]], u0, t_eval=t, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-6)
u9 = solve_ivp(grav, t[[0,-1]], u0, t_eval=t, atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-9)

plt.plot(t,u9.y[0]-u6.y[0]); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Of course relative to the range `[-1000, 4000]` of that component this is an error of `0.2 %` at the extreme, so below a visual difference if the graphs of the components are plotted together.

Still, it is far above the desired error level. Let's change that by providing a scale for the absolute error

```python
sc = np.concatenate([[1e3]*3,[1]*3])
def solve(tol): return solve_ivp(grav, t[[0,-1]], u0, t_eval=t, atol=sc*tol, rtol=tol)
u6 = solve(1e-6)
u7 = solve(1e-7)
u8 = solve(1e-8)
u9 = solve(1e-9)
```

That does not work as expected, between `u6` and `u9` the range of the error reduces by half, not by orders of magnitude. The error from `u8` to `u9` has a range to `0.2`, from `u7` to `u9` to `1.5`.

In a log-plot of the full position difference

```python
plt.semilogy(t,norm(u6.y[:3]-u9.y[:3])/norm(u9.y[:3])); 
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

one can see that the desired error level holds to about `t=3000`

[image]

After that it is more like the time axes are shifted, so that the position difference is more of being on the same orbit at different times than errors of the trajectory. Exactly the same pattern is obtained when comparing `u9` to `u12`, the latter at `tol=1e-12`, only with the error level reduced by `1e-3`.

This is likely an effect of long-term integration, either that the method step error has a noticeable component in direction of the trajectory, changing the speed along it, or that accumulated errors in the time step summation become noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you recommend then lowering the time interval or changing the method step error? Like for example from dormund prince to adams bashforth, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure if there really is a problem, that you need to change anything. The error scales with the tolerance, so you can keep it down or derive estimates for it in a semi-local fashion. It is not really astonishing that after long enough time scales the error becomes dominated by the shift between the solutions, as the distance between slightly different exact solutions, and behaves less like the local, method step error.

Comment: That makes sense for the larger time periods. I tried running it for a time of 10 and 3000 seconds instead of 4.2706e4 seconds, and the error between the two method still remains in roughly the 10^-3 range. Even with or without the tolerances the error seems to still be in the 10^-3 range. So, I think the tolerance is the problem, as it is not recognizing it for some reason.